# Lighthouse Version used for PageSpeed tests

Tags: performance, pagespeed, lighthouse, psi

I'm trying to figure out which version of Lighthouse is used by PAgeSpeed tests, is it 5.x or 6.x?
I have benn checking all the documentation i have found but no specific mention to the version on any of it.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

[Lighthouse 6 is still in Beta](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/changelog.md), published at 11.03.2020.

[PageSpeed runs Lighthouse 5](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/release_notes), published at 07.05.2019